# Difference between Multistage Sampling and Stratified Random Sampling?

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, stratification

I know the question is a very elementary one, but I simply cannot understand the difference other than the fact that an SRS is a form of Multi-Stage Sampling. Can anyone provide a *simple* example(s) to help me understand the critical difference between these two sampling designs?

Answer (score 2):

**Multi-Stage Sampling:**

Population: USA elementary school students

First stage sampling: 10 States from total of 50 States.

Second Stage: 20 Counties from total XX counties in selected XXXXX state in the first stage.

Third stage: 50 elementary schools from total yy elementary schools in the selected ZZZ county in the second stage

Fourth stage: 10 students from each selected school.

Finally, I got 10 * 50 * 20 * 10 = 100,000 students.

**Stratified sampling:**

Population: USA elementary school students

Geographically stratify USA into ten regions

```
Region I: Connecticut, Maine, Massachusetts, New Hampshire, Rhode Island, Vermont
Region II: New Jersey, New York, Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands
Region III: Delaware, District of Columbia, Maryland, Pennsylvania, Virginia, West Virginia
Region IV: Alabama, Florida, Georgia, Kentucky, Mississippi, North Carolina, South Carolina, Tennessee
Region V: Illinois, Indiana, Michigan, Minnesota, Ohio, Wisconsin
Region VI: Arkansas, Louisiana, New Mexico, Oklahoma, Texas
Region VII: Iowa, Kansas, Missouri, Nebraska
Region VIII: Colorado, Montana, North Dakota, South Dakota, Utah, Wyoming
Region IX: Arizona, California, Hawaii, Nevada, American Samoa, Guam, Northern Mariana Islands
Region X: Alaska, Idaho, Oregon, Washington
```

Randomly select 10,000 students from elementary schools from each region. I got a sample with 100,000 students.